# Change default cron log location

Tags: cron, virtuozzo

I have apache server with `$HOME` is `var/www/`, I create a cron job and all logs get into that directory, how to change it to another folder? Is there any config file on apache to change that? Btw, I'm using Jelastic/Virtuozzo

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: @RomeoNinov sorry, I can't find what I need on that link. Can u be more specific at what section i have to read?